# How best to architect django models to fit a scenario?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm modeling a system involving a process using a small number of inputs in a recipe to create outputs. The inputs have a subset of the attributes of outputs, but the complication is that outputs can also be used as inputs. The recipes need different quantities of different inputs. Ideally, I'd like to do this:

```
class CommonAttrs(models.Model):
    name = model.CharField()
    value = model.FloatField()
    cost = model.FloatField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Input(CommonAttrs):
    pass

class Output(CommonAttrs):
    price = model.FloatField()
    demand = model.FloatField()
    ...

class Recipe(models.Model):
    output = model.ForeignKey(Output)
    input_1 = model.OneToMany([Input, Output])  # I can dream
    quantity_1 = model.FloatField()
    input_2 = model.OneToMany([Input, Output])
    quantity_2 = model.FloatField()
    input_3 = model.OneToMany([Input, Output])
    quantity_3 = model.FloatField()
    input_4 = model.OneToMany([Input, Output])
    quantity_4 = model.FloatField()
```

However, in lieu of a OneToMany relationship in django, I've done:

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    output = model.ForeignKey(Output)
    input = model.ManyToManyField(Input, through='Measures')

class Measures(models.Model):
    recipe = model.ForeignKey(Recipe)
    input = model.ForeignKey(Input)
    quantity = model.FloatField()
```

That's all fine, but misses the crucial detail of outputs also being inputs of the recipe. I created a view in my database and attempted to create a new unmanaged model to in place of Input:

```
class InputOrOutput(CommonAttrs):

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'input_union_output_view'  # Does what is says on the tin
```

However this lead to a quagmire of problems with initialization and migrations.

My last resort would be creating a full-fledged table instead of a view, but that feels like asking for a headache from inconsistent data.

What are better options?

Comment: OK. So an output can also be an input. First thing I'd wonder about is if it would make more sense to have these in one table, perhaps with a boolean to signal "input only" if that's relevant. If what you're trying to do with `input_1` is link to either an Input *or* an output, that's actually possible, it just requires more fields. Happy to provide some code if we can clarify the necessity of separating these into two tables. Generic FK doc here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations

Comment: As a second question, do you *truly* want to design in a specific number of inputs/outputs in a Recipe, or do you want many inputs/outputs for each recipe? Are inputs/outputs used in more than one Recipe?

Comment: Never mind, you should start with the answer provided. It may need adjustment for your exact case, but it's a great start.

Comment: The inputs & outputs are referenced other places and are part of other systems independently from one another. There are enough places where I need to reference only the inputs or only the outputs that combining constantly filtering for a flag on the combined table would be bothersome. Also, I want to treat them as separate semantically. As far as hard-coded recipes are concerned, code generation would take care of it, but the lack of a one-to-many relationship necessitates the intermediary table, anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming, per the comments that Inputs and Outputs can't go in the same table, then a Generic Foreign Key is probably your best option to have a relationship that binds to either model. To start with your Recipe code:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

class Recipe(models.Model):
    output = model.ForeignKey(Output)
    input_1_content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    input_1_object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    input_1_content_object = GenericForeignKey('input_1_content_type', 'input_1_object_id')
    quantity_1 = model.FloatField()
```

This would get you a generic FK for your input_1. That's a lot of code if you have to do each input manually, but maybe that's OK.

It would be nice if there were a simple way to do generic M2M out of the box, but I don't believe there is. Instead, perhaps an intermediate class would get you most of the way there:

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    output = model.ForeignKey(Output)
    @property
    def inputs(self):
        return self.recipeinput_set


class RecipeInput(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    quantity = model.FloatField()
```

Comment: Thanks! Generic relations seem to be precisely what I'm looking for. And since the reverse relation needs to be defined manually, the intermediary class is the much saner option.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what an `Input` or an `Output` is, I'll assume its food. Which is handy.

A recipe uses food to produce a different type of food.

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    output = model.ForeignKey(Food, related_name="produced_by")
    input = model.ManyToManyField(Food, through='Measures')
```

For example (this code may or may not work, but illustrates the point):

```
cheese = Food("Cheese")
bread  = Food("Bread")
toasty = Food("Toasted Cheese Sandwich")

toasty.produced_by = Recipe(input=[cheese,bread])
```

A input measure then just references a `Food` item.

```
class Measures(models.Model):
    recipe = model.ForeignKey(Recipe)
    input = model.ForeignKey(Food)
    quantity = model.FloatField()
```

Each `Food` then has a purchase and sale price - assuming there is nothing stopping me from buying cheese and then selling it.

```
class Food(models.Model):
    name = model.CharField()
    value = model.FloatField()
    purchase_price = model.FloatField()
    sale_price = model.FloatField()
    demand = model.FloatField()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, inputs & outputs are substantively different, used in different places, and I wish to treat them as such semantically. Additionally, in this case, these inputs are the result of a different process that cannot produce these outputs.